# CNAME would only connect ipv6 connection

Tags: cname-record

I signed up for freenet6's ipv6 tunnel. Everyone (even ipv4) can access my XAMPP server by using http://myaccount.broker.freenet6.net no problem. What I want to accomplish is to setup a domain instead of using the free domain provided by freenet6. So I put a CNAME record for subdomain.mydomain.com and pointed it to myaccount.broker.freenet6.net, the problem here is that only ipv6 connection can browse the site if you try to access it using subdomain.mydomain.com. Am i doing something wrong here? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated..

why can't ipv4 connections detect the domain after the CNAME is in place? These are the domains so you can check on your own. Original domain by freenet6 = akosiboybastos.broker.freenet6.net accessible via ipv4 and ipv6. my test domain bastosforum.strangled.net (can only be accessed by ipv6) which has a CNAME record directed to akosiboybastos.broker.freenet6.net.
Thanks

BB

Comment: Can you post the output of `host subdomain.mydomain.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, now we have the real DNS records, we can do some diagnosis.

`dig` for both A and AAAA on `akosiboybastos.broker.freenet6.net` gives a valid response, with an appropriate address.  Good.

`dig` for both A and AAAA on `bastosforum.strangled.net` gives the same responses (with a CNAME response thrown in).  Also good.  This means that the problem is *not* DNS-related, as those records are in order.

`wget -6 http://bastosforum.strangled.net/` gives a `200 OK` response.

`wget -4 http://bastosforum.strangled.net/` gives a `404 Not Found` response.  This means that your webserver is misconfigured so that it's not serving the response you desire on IPv4.  Given that the initial DNS problem asked in this question has been solved, I would recommend posting a new question with relevant webserver-related configuration, if you can't determine the configuration error yourself.

Comment: thanks man, this has been the best response that i got, even for a newbie like me everything makes sense now. I will post a new question as soon as I can more info about this webserver misconfiguration, Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

A CNAME record won't work in this scenario. The web server you redirect to has to be aware of the redirect and set up to support it.

Instead, set up an AAAA record with your IPv6 address.

Comment: I don't see why a CNAME record won't work in this case.

Comment: A CNAME won't work because freenet6's web server isn't going to answer for @boyb's domain name.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: What's that got to do with anything?  The CNAME will reference the freenet6 address, which (apparently) has A and AAAA records (based on the OP's statement that "Everyone (even ipv4) can access my XAMPP server").

Comment: @womble then why can't ipv4 connections detect the domain after the CNAME is in place? These are the domains so you can check on your own. Original domain by freenet6 = akosiboybastos.broker.freenet6.net accessible via ipv4 and ipv6. my test domain http://bastosforum.strangled.net (can only be accessed by ipv6) which has a CNAME record directed to akosiboybastos.broker.freenet6.net.

Comment: @boyb: That information would be best added to your question, rather than as a comment on an answer.